# Automator services replace selected text's spaces with underscore

Tags: automator, script

Looking to create a simple automator service that I can use when selecting text. If the text has spaces, it will replace it with underscores.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I mean what effort you have put in so far? Please feel free to share any code snippet  that you have written and describe the challenges that you have faced.

Comment: Input is text in any application. Which then leads to shell script in perl: rename "s/ /_/g" * (found on internet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example of how it can be achieved using an **Automator** *Service* and a **Run AppleScript** *action*:

```
on run {input}
    set input to replaceText(" ", "_", input as string)
end run

on replaceText(find, replace, textString)
    set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to find
    set textString to text items of textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to replace
    set textString to "" & textString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
    return textString
end replaceText
```

Set the *service* to the settings shown in the image below:

- Note that in **macOS Mojave** a *service* is now called a *Quick Action*.

[image: Automator Service]

---

Note that the `replaceText(find, replace, textString)` *handler* was something I found on the Internet too many years ago to remember where and give credit to its source.